# How to send OK response to EWS

Tags: c#, soap, exchangewebservices

I am trying to get EWS's push notifications set up in my c# app.

After getting the response from the server and reading it using a NetworkStream I need to respond to the server with Ok in a SOAP message.  The only example that I can find uses Microsoft.Web.Services3 and a SoapEnvelope.  My understanding is that this has now been replaced by WCF and I really want to use the newer technologies (to learn them).

How would I go by sending a SOAP message back to the server, presumably using the same NetworkStream that I get the notification on?

Here is some code that I tried, but it fails for some reason.

```
const string RESPONSE_OK = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope\"><soap:Body>" +
                "<SendNotificationResult xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages\">" +
                "<SubscriptionStatus>OK</SubscriptionStatus></SendNotificationResult></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>";

responseBytes = encoding.GetBytes(RESPONSE_OK);

             // Send the result
             HTTPResponseStruct _httpResponse;
            _httpResponse.version = "HTTP/1.1";
            _httpResponse.BodyData = responseBytes;

            _httpResponse.Headers = new Hashtable();
            _httpResponse.Headers.Add("Server", "IT12");
            _httpResponse.Headers.Add("Date", DateTime.Now.ToString("r"));
            _httpResponse.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
            _httpResponse.Headers.Add("Content-Length", _httpResponse.BodyData.Length);
            _httpResponse.Headers.Add("Connection", "close");


            string HeadersString = _httpResponse.version + " "
               + "200 OK" + "\r\n";

            foreach (DictionaryEntry Header in _httpResponse.Headers)
            {
                HeadersString += Header.Key + ": " + Header.Value + "\r\n";
            }

            HeadersString += "\r\n";

            byte[] bHeadersString = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(HeadersString);

            // Send headers   
            clientStream.Write(bHeadersString, 0, bHeadersString.Length);


            // Send body
            if (_httpResponse.BodyData != null)
                clientStream.Write(_httpResponse.BodyData, 0,
                         _httpResponse.BodyData.Length);
           // clientStream.Write(responseBytes, 0, responseBytes.Length);
            clientStream.Flush();
```

Thanks,
Pieter

Comment: You forgot to mention anything about how it fails. Include exception types, error messages, or describe the unexpected behaviour.

Comment: EWS notifies me of a change, then I am supposed to let it know I got the notification.  If not then it will try again in 30, then 1 min and keep on doubling the time until it reaches the time specified in my subscription (5 mins) and then unsubscribe me automatically.  There are no exceptions, just a few more notifications until it stops.

Comment: did you managed to get it working?

Comment: I'm having the same issue - doesn't the managed api support this behavier or do i need to do some soap thingy like you suggested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data (EWS Managed API Reference)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633710%28v=EXCHG.80%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks, this lead me to the page I was looking for: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg236898(v=EXCHG.140).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You marked the other answer as "accepted" but the link you are referring to talks about streaming subscriptions. These are only available for Exchange 2010 and later. For those who are stuck with Exchange Server 2007, there is a [Push-Notification library](http://exchangenotification.codeplex.com/) on CodePlex.